# Android sqlite near (1) syntax error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have used sqlite in my application, successfully i have implemented but while creating database it shows sqlite near(1) syntax error

Check it out my code

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEYID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + DRIVER_ID
            + " text not null, " + DEVICE_ID + " text not null " + COORDINATES
            + " text not null " + TIMESTAMP + " text not null " + USERNAME
            + " text not null " + SampleID + " text not null );";
```

Check it out my log

```
11-14 15:08:26.899: E/SQLiteLog(24098): (1) near "latlong": syntax error
```

Anyone please help me to get solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to add `,(comma)` in your SQL command

### try this below

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
        + KEYID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + DRIVER_ID+ " text not null, " 
        + DEVICE_ID + " text not null, " 
        + COORDINATES + " text not null, " 
        + TIMESTAMP + " text not null, " 
        + USERNAME + " text not null, " 
        + SampleID + " text not null);";
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put "," in your syntax.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEYID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + DRIVER_ID
            + " text not null, " + DEVICE_ID + " text not null, " + COORDINATES
            + " text not null, " + TIMESTAMP + " text not null, " + USERNAME
            + " text not null, " + SampleID + " text not null );";
```